# Using share preference to save some a few int

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

android, java, sharedpreferences, datad during the run . What I want is that if I close or  pause  my  app  the  ints value are saved, so when I open it back again I can  have the last value back.

I have this so far, trying with 1 int to learn how to.

```
protected void onPause(){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); 
    editor.putInt("valueSave",valueToSave ); 
    editor.commit();
} 

@Override 
protected void onResume(){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 
}
```

But values are not saved... what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: onCreate added

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.program);
    //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    //settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    valueToSave = settings.getInt("valueSave",valueToSave);
```

Comment: Have you tried to actually get the saved integer from your `SharedPreferences` object? E.g. try `valueToSave = settings.getInt(PREFS_NAME, 0)` in your `onResume()` method to retrieve it.

Comment: Added it and asked to add super.onResume() and super.onPause(). But still getting initial value

Comment: Sorry, my earlier suggestion should've been `valueToSave = settings.getInt("valueSave", 0)`, but you've probably figured that out by now - note the key `"valueSave"`. Did have a look at the [examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) on the Android dev website as well?

Comment: And that 0 is its value?

Comment: That is the default value that should be assigned to the variable in case the preference does not (yet) exist. In your case this should never happen, except the very first time the app is used (because `onPause()` will not have been called yet in that scenario). Obviously you can change the `0` to a more appropriate value for your use case.

Comment: Ok let me see if I understand this. The default value will be 0 if I add "valueSave",0, right? Then in pause how do I set new value? Like this "valueSave, valueToSave" (valueToSave is changed with on click of a text)

Comment: No, `valueToSave = settings.getInt("valueSave", 0)` will return the value stored with the key `"valueSave"`, or `0` in case the key does not exist in the preferences. `editor.putInt("valueSave", valueToSave);` (and then commit) will set the value for the preference identified by the key `"valueSave"` to the second argument. Based on your other comment: if you're getting a cast error, you're probably using the wrong `put...()` method (and/or variable type).

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That make me understand how it works and is working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting a SharedPreference using the application context in this way:

To save preferences:

```
int valueToSave = 1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
editor.putInt("someValue", valueToSave);
editor.commit();
```

To retreive from preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int savedvalue = settings.getInt("someValue");
```

Comment: You can use it anywhere as long as you can supply the right context to  it. (In this case, you want the application context).  Also, sorry I left out the important class qualifier, I'm using PreferenceManager to get the shared preferences, instead of the activity helper method.

Comment: But how this knows whats the right value? Added it to onCreate but it's not working...

Comment: That line gives you access to a preference object shared by all components in the application.  You can then grab your value out of it in the next line using int savedValue = settings.getInt("valueSave");

Comment: I added my onCreat... oooo I think I spotted the error. Let me check

Comment: It gives error here settings.getInt("someValue"); says String cat be add to int